# Current density for discrete charges

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose I have N charges with the same charge q in volume V but moving at different velocities in the x direction. Then is the current density given by
$$J = (N/V) q v_{avg}$$
or is it
$$J = (N/V) q \sum_{i} v_i$$

The second one makes more sense to me because a current of 5A and 3A in the x direction combine to make a current of 8A. This shouldn't work with the first equation because if both flows contain the same amount of charges, then the average velocity would cause the current to be somewhere between 5 and 3.

But then what is v in the equation $J = \rho v$? All this time it was the average velocity $<v>$.

Comment: This particular question, it maybe worth to look into the Physics NCERT Class-12 Current electricity chapter. It has a brief discussion on calculating this. HC Verma has an alternate derivation to it (controversial), and I guess Griffith could also be consulted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current density by itself, does not use the average velocity. It uses the instantaneous velocity of a charge density in location your evaluating current density.

Current density is defined at every point in space, so when a charge is there, the actual velocity is the most correct to use.

As far as I am aware, 2 seperate current density functions (for example 2 point charges) cannot occupy the same location in space, so taking the "average" velocity doesn't make sense as there is only 1 velocity to be considered at a particular point in space.

You are confusing current and current density. If there are 2 seperate current density functions, then  the current across a particular  cross section COULD cancel out,

As current is

$$ I = \iint \vec{J} \cdot \vec{da} $$

If half of the contributions are one way  and half another, then net current is zero

You seem to be talking about current and not current density

Answer (score 0):

The correct formula is the first one, with ${\bf v}_\text{avg}$, because ${\bf J}$ is. itself, a vector. In your case, you could say $J_x=(N/V)q\bar{v}_x$. Just summing over the velocities does not make much sense, because as $N$ can be very extremely large, summing over all velocities would lead to huge currents, which would be very wrong. Remember: we don't care about the individual velocities of each particle, only at their general movement.

If we apply an electric field ${\bf E}$ to a conductor, we want to know on average what happens, because each charge will, still, have a more or less random velocity (caused by thermal energy). If, in this example, we find that we do have an average velocity being generated by the electric field, well, then we have current. That is the idea.

Comment: Why does summing over velocities giving huge current not make sense? If summing over velocities gives a large number, then the intuition is dq/dt is large. Also I edited the question a bit. Could you address what I said about averaging currents?